# How do you use the Group Statement on your SQL to Linq queries?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I would like to end up with a list where my categories are grouped according to the users id.

```
      IEnumerable<JoinClass> catList =
                        from c in db.Users2
                        join e in db.Categories on c.Id_Users equals e.FK_Users
                        where c.EEID == UserEEID
                        group e.Category by c.EEID in z
                        select new JoinClass
                        {
                            Category = e.Category,
                            EEID = c.EEID,
                        };

         return View(catList.ToList() );
```

Comment: you don't show the definition of JoinClass.  Also, how is this code not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
  IEnumerable<JoinClass> catList =
                    from c in db.Users2
                    join e in db.Categories on c.Id_Users equals e.FK_Users
                    where c.EEID == UserEEID
                    group e.Category by c.EEID in z
                    select new JoinClass
                    {
                        Categories = z.ToList(),
                        EEID = z.Key,
                    };

     return View(catList.ToList() );
```

Assuming you ACTUALLY meant to find all Categories for each EEID.